# Early return in functions and yield

Tags: php, generator, yield

I'm not sure what the correct way is to early return in a function when using the `yield` keyword.

Is a "return void" `return;` the correct return value? Because the return type is specified to be `iterable`. Although it works without any error, returning void if the type hint would be `int` would lead to an error. So is `iterable` type hint an exception to still accept a void return statement although the type hint indicates something `iterable` should be returned?

See the example below to clarify my question:

```
class Collection
{
    public $items;
}

class OrderedCollection extends Collection
{
    public $orderedItems;
}

class Test
{
    public function getCollectionItems(Collection $collection): iterable
    {
        if ($collection instanceof OrderedCollection) {
            yield from $collection->orderedItems;
            return; // What should I return here to early exit the function?
        }

        yield from $collection->items;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could change it to use `else { yield from $collection->items; };`

Comment: @NigelRen this would be an option. But I'm interested if there is a solution without else. :-)

Comment: @NigelRen that would not have been early exit